# Hibernate - lazy loading is getting childs even if I don't fetch them

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, lazy-loading

I have some lazy hibernate configuration that is loading childs of its parent, even if I don't fetch them

I have the following hibernate configuration

In the parent hbm.xml

```
<set name="childs" table="CHILD" cascade="all" lazy="true" inverse="true">
  <key>
    <column name="childid" not-null="true" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="com.mysite.Child" />
</set>
```

My HQL query is

```
select p from Parent p where p.type = ?
```

As you see, my query is not trying to access Child but when the result comes, it comes with the child as well

Any idea why?

Thanks,

Comment: Check logs or console and see which queries are actually being fired when you execute this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with adding one more attribute to set tag as fetch="select"?

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate official](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties) says about using lazy property fetching, the following:

> Lazy property loading requires buildtime bytecode instrumentation. If your persistent classes are not enhanced, Hibernate will ignore lazy property settings and return to immediate fetching.

So, if your are not instrumenting your code, your collections will be fetched immediately although you have configured them with lazy.

Are you sure you have instrumented your bytecode? If you don't know, what are you using to manage your code? ant, maven, gradle, ... ?

## Edit

If you don't know what instrumentation is, you have a nice read [here](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-bytecode-enhancement/).

Comment: I´m using maven. I didn't know about the bytecode instrumentation

Comment: nice article, the project I'm working on is kind of big. I was checking the pom file but I haven't seen any additional hibernate configuration on it or similar to what you mention. If I want lazy to work correctly, do I need to setup this in the pom? or it can be in java code? because I'm not sure if I can modify or add any configuration in the pom

Comment: You can add hibernate maven ant-run plugin into your build/plugins section of your pom. It is safe to do. If you don't have build section in your pom, then you can add entirely. If you are in doubt, you can post your pom in your question and I can tell you what to do.

Comment: Since this project has a lot of java projects, I'm trying to find the pom which has the hibernate configuration but I can't yet. I have a question, if I add the configuration you are talking about to the pom, will it affect existing functionalities /queries/etc?

Comment: You can try it, it won't change your existing functionality. But once you get lazy collections loading, you must be aware of lazyness, so you can get lazy exceptions ...